# How to calculate total price of a product in models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to calculate discount on products.I am calculating the price in models.py using @property. But the problem I am facing is that the product table is in Product app (models.py) which contains price however the quantity is in the Cart app (models.py). And for total I want to multiply **price*quantity**. The error I am facing is that the get_total_price is not calculating the amount.
**view.py**

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Carts(request)
    coupon_apply_form = CouponApplyForm()
    context = {
            'cart':cart,
            'coupon_apply_form':coupon_apply_form
        }
    return render(request,'carts/coupon.html',context)
```

**Cart/models.py**

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
cart=models.ForeignKey('Cart',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Cart(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    total= models.DecimalField( default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
```

**Product/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
 price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=0.00)
```

In my **Cart/models.py**

```
class Carts(object):
"""docstring for Cart"""
def __init__(self, request):
    """initalize the cart"""
    self.session = request.session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)

    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    self.cart = cart
    self.coupon_id = self.session.get('coupon_id')

def __len__(self):
    return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

def get_total_price(self):
    return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())


def clear(self):
    del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
    self.session.modified = True


@property
def coupon(self):
    if self.coupon_id:
        return Coupons.objects.get(id=self.coupon_id)
    return None

def get_discount(self):
    if self.coupon:
        return (self.coupon.discount / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()
    return Decimal('0')

def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
    return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
```

In the above code when I remove the self.get_total_price from get_total_price_after_discount and then the discount price displays otherwise its showing 0.00.

**Cart/template.html**

```
<table>
{% if cart.coupon %}
                    <tr class="gray2">
                        {% block trans   %}
                            {% with code=cart.coupon.code discount=cart.coupon.discount %}
                    <td colspan="2">"{{code}}" coupon ({{discount}})% off</td>
                            {% endwith %}
                    {% endblock trans %}
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                    <td class="num neg"> {{cart.get_discount|floatformat:"2"}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
                    <tr class="total">
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                    <td class="num">{{cart.get_total_price_after_discount|floatformat:"2"}}</td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

But it's displaying the total as 0.00. I have also tried it as:

```
   def get_total_price(self):
            return self.product.price* self.cartitem.quantity
```

But all in vain nothing worked. Please help me in this regard?

**Note:** 
I have made a function in cart/views.py fro calculating the total. Can i call use that calculation somehow in cart/models.py.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

We can calculate an aggregate in the `Cart` model, like:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.db.models import F, Sum

class Cart(models.Model):

    # ...

    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.cartitem_set.aggregate(
            total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'))
        )['total_price'] or Decimal('0')
```

For a `Cart` we can thus render this as:

```
<td class="num">{{ cart.total_price|floatformat:"2" }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanku so much for your response. But It didn't  print anything @Willem Sir not even 0

Comment: @Samavi: is your `cart` in the template a `Cart` object?

Comment: @Samavi: can you share the view that you are using? You did change the template to `{{ cart.total_price|...}}` right?

Comment: Ya i have shared the same. @Willem i edited my question cart/models.py please have a look for further understanding

Comment: @Samavi: but the question does not contain the view function that is triggered here.

Comment: @Wlliem sorry for the inconvenience. Added view.py. I hope it helps

Comment: @Samavi: but your `cart` here is *not* a `Cart` object, it is just a **dictionary**.

Comment: sorry i was mistaken @Willem .Please suggest any solution?